# Dirichlet transform of $e^{(2 \pi i / 3) \Omega(n)}$

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series, liouville-function

The [Dirichlet transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series) of the [Liouville function $\lambda(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function) is [famously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4124768/the-dirichlet-series-for-the-liouville-function-related-to-the-riemann-zeta-func/4124782#comment8699887_4124782)

$$ \sum_{n=1} \frac{\lambda(n)}{n^s} = \frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)}\tag{1}$$

The Liouville function is defined by $$ \lambda(n) = (-1)^{\Omega(n)}\tag{2} $$ with [$\Omega(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function) being the number of not-necessarily distinct prime factors of the natural number $n$.

I am interested in the Dirichlet transform of a similar (completely multiplicative) function $f$ defined as
$$ f(n):= e^{(2 \pi i / 3)\Omega(n)} \tag{3}$$

I have got that far in the evaluation:

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
   \sum_{n=1} \frac{f(n)}{n^s}  & = & \sum_{n=1} \frac{e^{(2 \pi i / 3)\Omega(n)}}{n^s} \nonumber \\
 & = & \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \left( \sum_{k=0} \frac{e^{(2 \pi i / 3)k}}{p^{ks}}  \right)   = \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \left( \sum_{k=0} \left(\frac{e^{(2 \pi i / 3)}}{p^{s}}\right)^k  \right)\nonumber \\ 
 & = & \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \frac{1}{ 1 - \frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}}}  \tag{5} \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

at this point I am not completely sure how to continue. In analogy to the case of the Dirichlet transformation of $\lambda(n)$ one could expand these fractions in trinomial fashion possibly by a factor of $ \frac{1}{1 + \frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}} + \left(\frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}}\right)^2}$ that would yield

$$\begin{eqnarray} \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \frac{1}{ 1 - \frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}}} \cdot \frac{{1 + \frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}} + \left(\frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}}\right)^2}}{{1 + \frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}} + \left(\frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}}\right)^2}} & = & \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \frac{{1 + \frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}} + \left(\frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}}\right)^2}}{ 1 - \left(\frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}}\right)^3 } \nonumber \\
 & = & \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \frac{{1 + \frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}} + \left(\frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}}\right)^2}}{ 1 - \frac{1}{p^{3s}} } \nonumber  \\
 & = & \zeta(3s) \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \left({1 + \frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}} + \left(\frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}}\right)^2}\right) \nonumber  \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

setting $\beta(p)=\frac{e^{2 \pi i / 3}}{p^{s}}$ I obtain

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1} \frac{f(n)}{n^s} & = & \zeta(3s) \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} 
(1 + \beta(p) + \beta^2(p)) & \nonumber  \\
& = &\zeta(3s) \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \left(\beta(p) - \frac{i\sqrt{3}-1}{2}\right) \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \left(\beta(p) + \frac{i\sqrt{3}+1}{2}\right)
\end{eqnarray}$$

Here I get a bit stuck, the hope would be that one would be able to express the whole thing in terms of elementary functions.

Any help appreciated.

---

Edit

From here I can slightly proceed by

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \left(\beta(p) - \frac{i\sqrt{3}-1}{2}\right) \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \left(\beta(p) + \frac{i\sqrt{3}+1}{2}\right) & = & \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \left(\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2} - \beta(p)\right) \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \left(\frac{i\sqrt{3}+1}{2} + \beta(p)\right) 
\end{eqnarray}$$

by defining the constants $\alpha_{1/2}:=\frac{2e^{2\pi i / 3}}{(+/-)1-i\sqrt{3}}$ this can be rewritten to

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \left(\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2} - \beta(p)\right) \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \left(\frac{i\sqrt{3}+1}{2} + \beta(p)\right) & = & \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \left(1-\frac{\alpha_1}{p^s}\right) \prod_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \left(1-\frac{\alpha_2}{p^s}\right)
\end{eqnarray}$$

These expressions look up to the factors $\alpha$ very similar to the Euler Product of $\zeta^{-1}$, but I am not aware of if this can be simplified any further.

Comment: I don't see a reason to expect this to be expressible in $\zeta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case, it is possible to write the Dirichlet series in the following product. Let $|z|\leq R <2$. Then

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^{\Omega(n)} n^{-s} = \zeta(s)^z F(s,z)
$$
where
$$
F(s,z) = \prod_p \left( 1- \frac z{p^s}\right)^{-1}\left(1-\frac 1{p^s}\right)^z
$$
is absolutely convergent for $\Re(s)>\frac12$.

Thus, you can try putting $z=e^{2\pi i/3}$.

For a general method, you can refer to Montgomery, Vaughan's Multiplicative Number Theory, classical theory I, p.232 Theorem 7.18.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is good to know that there is a formal way to proceed. Unfortunately inserting this $z=e(1/3)$ into the Montgomery expression yields exactly my $(5)$, which is a nice confirmation that everything is OK up to that point. So it seems we cannot proceed further, can we?

Comment: Yes, everything is okay up to (5). An advantage of this approach is to factor out $\zeta(s)^z$. This allows having $F(s,z)$ with a Dirichlet series absolutely convergent over a larger region than $\zeta$. I forgot to mention in my answer that the name of this approach is "Selberg-DeLange method".

Comment: Another place to look up the method is Tenenbaum's Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory II.5, p185, Theorem 3. This version is a stronger theorem than Montgomery, Vaughan's Theorem 7.18.